# Custom Popup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to create custom popup dialog with Editor inside it using Xamarin Forms. Targeted to iOS platform.

I want a pop up with a Title Label ,Text box for accepting input and error Label for displaying error message, with OK and Cancel button.

I want to accept pin number from input pop up and have to validate pin. If validation fails I have to show a Error message inside pop up.

Thanks,

Comment: What are your requirements of said popup? Does it need to be fully customizable?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell : updated text please check for my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at ACR User Dialogs. https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

Then have a look at the Prompt Examples: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/StandardViewModel.cs#L97

```
void Prompt()
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(new ActionSheetConfig()
                .SetTitle("Choose Type")
                .Add("Default", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Default))
                .Add("E-Mail", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Email))
                .Add("Name", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Name))
                .Add("Number", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Number))
                .Add("Number with Decimal", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.DecimalNumber))
                .Add("Password", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Password))
                .Add("Numeric Password (PIN)", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.NumericPassword))
                .Add("Phone", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Phone))
                .Add("Url", () => this.PromptCommand(InputType.Url))
            );
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this, I was able to take input from popup but the problem is if the input is invalid I have to show error message inside popup, How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I would recommend doing something with behaviors if possible: https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/. Or at least use some kind of inline error messages

Comment: Thanks @Adam Pedley , How to add behaviours for acr popup.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good popup for XF that includes the ability to add an editor to the popup.

[Popup Page Plugin for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

```
// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync
```

XAML POPUP PAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="Demo.Pages.MyPopupPage">
  <!--Animations use example-->
  <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center"
      PositionOut="Center"
      ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8"
      DurationIn="400"
      DurationOut="300"
      EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn"
      HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
  </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
  <!-- Content -->
</pages:PopupPage>
```

POPUP PAGE

```
public partial class MyPopupPage : PopupPage
    {
        public SecondPopupPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        // Method for animation child in PopupPage
        // Invoced after custom animation end
        protected virtual Task OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(0.5);
        }

        // Method for animation child in PopupPage
        // Invoked before custom animation begin
        protected virtual Task OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(1);;
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // Prevent hide popup
            //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true; 
        }

        // Invoced when background is clicked
        protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            // Return default value - CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked
            return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
        }
    }
```

MAINPAGE

```
    // Main Page

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Button Click
        private async void OnOpenPupup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var page = new MyPopupPage();

            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);
            // or
            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your other answer was deleted because it just contains a link. You can check via your user profile, activity tab, answers, "deleted recent answers" at the bottom of the answer list.

Comment: Can't we do it without using Nuget Package and custom renders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a custom popup can be added in Xamarin forms. Please follow these steps:

1. Create one stacklayout.
2. Add the fields in to the stacklayout.
3. Create one new Frame object.
4. Make the Frame object background with transaprent color.
5. Add the Stacklayout object into frame.
6. Add the frame to main content page.

If you need code, I will update.

Comment: I'm no expert on this problem, but, as a general rule, code (or at least some structure) should be added to help people forward

Comment: This won't show a popup window above the content of the main content page. It will either insert (.Insert or .Add) this new content (frame) inside the content of the main content page, or will replace the whole content of the main page (mainPage.Content = frame;). Is there a way to show this frame over the content of the main page?